# Failed glewInit: Missing GL version

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

I began to study OpenGL on the course.Download glew-2.1.0(64) and glfw-3.2.1(64). Like everything connected and IDE not swear but initialization produces the following output in the command line:

> Error initialization GLEW: Missing GL version

```
#include <iostream>
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
// GLFW
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
const char* APP_TITLE = "Introduction in modern openGL";

const int gWindowWidth = 800;
const int gWindowHeight = 600;

int main()
{
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed in initialization GLFW" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE); 
    GLFWwindow* pWindow = glfwCreateWindow(gWindowWidth, gWindowHeight, APP_TITLE, NULL, NULL);
    if (pWindow)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed in create Windows" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(pWindow);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != err)
    {

        std::cerr << "Error initialization GLEW: " << glewGetErrorString(err) << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(pWindow))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();

        glfwSwapBuffers(pWindow);

    }
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

What is the problem? I searched on the Internet, but there are solutions to problems of the type:

> add glfwMakeContextCurrent(game_window); before glewInit()

Comment: How do you add `glew` to your project, use the sources or the already compiled library?

Comment: @Ripi2,  Already compiled library

Comment: Then comment the line `#define GLEW_STATIC` and try again. Take a look at [glew doc](http://glew.sourceforge.net/install.html)

Comment: @Ripi2  [link](https://i.imgur.com/CGDx2id.png)

Comment: It seems the provided libs are not compatible, likely because they are 32bits instead of your 64bits enviroment. Remove them, add the glew sources to your project, enable GLEW_STATIC and try again.

Comment: @Ripi2 [link](https://imgur.com/a/BZVUT) I checked. GLEW was taken from x64 and GLFW was compiled in x64 mode

Answer (score 2):

Very stupid mistake

I wrote

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
```

I should have

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);  
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
```